# How can I monitor circuit network signal values?

Tags: factorio

I'd like to see what are the actual values of signals in the circuit network. This would be useful for both troubleshooting and to actually have an easy way to count items in storage chests, especially if there's a lot of them.

Is there a way to display circuit network channel values as numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out you can see the signal values when you hover electric pylon that has signal wires on it:

[image: image description]

Comment: Is there any way to see the values without hovering? That would be very useful.

Comment: Well, there's no HUD for it if that's what you're asking. You can try a mod or make one.

Answer (score 2):

The [wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Tutorial:Circuit-network_Cookbook#Numerical_Display) gives a blueprint for a digital-display

[image: Digital Display]

The blueprint is too large to post here, but an be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5o13xuwthalzzfe/Brain2.txt?dl=0) ([mirror](https://pastebin.com/zNW6zc56))

Comment: Not exactly practical, but quite cool.

Comment: If you're open to using mods, Nixie Tubes is marvellous.